# 'Popovers' to highlight areas of interest or new features?

Tags: ios, uipopover

I've noticed a lot of apps have a 'popover' that highlights areas of interest or new features (see pic for example).

[image]

What are these called? I dont believe there is a ready made solution to these in Apple docs apart from `iPad` `UIPopoverController`.

Sorry if this seems a bit subjective but I am unsure of what its called.

Would love if someone could point me in a right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's definitely a custom implementation. I figure they would be called tool tips or speech bubbles if describing them to someone.

There is  nice component to do it here: https://maniacdev.com/2014/07/open-source-ios-component-for-creating-animated-customizable-popover-tooltips